# Removing edit within switch statements

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am working on creating a poker odds calculator, I have 8 players set around a table with a JComboBox with the selected amount of players. What I am looking to do is to "repaint" the GUI after I make multiple selections. For example, if I click 4 players, 4 players become editable. This currently works but when I select 3 players after, player 4 is still editable.

I have tried to set the visibility, I tired to remove the player panes, I tried remove(addPlayer4), I have tried a few other odd things but the closest I can get is removing the player entirely.

```
addPlayer1.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        player1.removeAll();
        player1.add(playerPanelFactory("Player1",1));
        //welcomeScreen.get
        repaint();
        validate();
    });
    addPlayer2.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        player2.removeAll();
        player2.add(playerPanelFactory("Player2",2));
        getParent().repaint();
 //       contentPane.repaint();
        validate();
    });
    addPlayer3.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        player3.removeAll();
        player3.add(playerPanelFactory("Player3",3));
        getParent().repaint();
//        contentPane.repaint();
        validate();
    });
    addPlayer4.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        player4.removeAll();
        player4.add(playerPanelFactory("Player4",4));
        repaint();
        validate();
    });
```

.....

```
playerBox.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)-> {
        numberOfPlayers = playerBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPlayers);
        switch(numPlayers){
            case 1: 
                addPlayer1.doClick();
                break;
            case 2:
                addPlayer1.doClick();
                addPlayer2.doClick();
                break;
            case 3:
                addPlayer1.doClick();
                addPlayer2.doClick();
                addPlayer3.doClick();
                break;
            case 4:
                addPlayer1.doClick();
                addPlayer2.doClick();
                addPlayer3.doClick();
                addPlayer4.doClick();
                break;
            case 5:
                addPlayer1.doClick();
                addPlayer2.doClick();
                addPlayer3.doClick();
                addPlayer4.doClick();
                addPlayer5.doClick();
                break;
            case 6:
                addPlayer1.doClick();
                addPlayer2.doClick();
                addPlayer3.doClick();
                addPlayer4.doClick();
                addPlayer5.doClick();
                addPlayer6.doClick();
                break;
            case 7:
                addPlayer1.doClick();
                addPlayer2.doClick();
                addPlayer3.doClick();
                addPlayer4.doClick();
                addPlayer5.doClick();
                addPlayer6.doClick();
                addPlayer7.doClick();
                break;
            case 8:
                addPlayer1.doClick();
                addPlayer2.doClick();
                addPlayer3.doClick();
                addPlayer4.doClick();
                addPlayer5.doClick();
                addPlayer6.doClick();
                addPlayer7.doClick();
                addPlayer8.doClick();

                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    });
```

I didn't want to link all of the code since it is almost 700 lines but I believe this is where the issues could be. The goal I am looking to get is to have the players pane editable when they are selected and not editable when not selected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLMUZ.jpg?
I hope this makes sense

Comment: Please add a clear problem statement regarding what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this adaptation will help fix your problem. Essentially you are adding a number of players every time you change the counter, re-adding them on every change, e.g. when 1 player is selected, you spawn player 1. Then when two players are selected, you spawn player 1 again and player 2. Perhaps adding in a check of some sorts so that you aren't re-creating the same players again would be good, then you wouldn't have to clear the players every time they are added, though only a minor thought.

With this suggestion, the aim is to basically compare the current number of player to the previous number. If we are adding more players or staying the same, continue as normal and update our variables. If we are however removing one or more players, remove the player in between our current number of players, and our target number of players, before re-drawing.

Example case: going from 7 players to 5 players. Therefore we want to delete new number of player (5) + 1, so player 6. Then loop round and delete the last player, player 7. Then redraw.

I haven't been able to test it without the code, but I hope my brainstorm helps, or that it sparks some thoughts to either yourself or someone else :) Hopefully it is implementable as well. If anyone know of a better way of doing this, I'm all ears as well and eager to learn where I may have gone wrong! :)

```
int lastNumPlayers;

/*
*   SOME CODE
*/

playerBox.addActionListener((ActionEvent e)-> {
        numberOfPlayers = playerBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPlayers);

        if(numPlayers >= lastNumPlayers) {
            switch(numPlayers){
                case 1: 
                    addPlayer1.doClick();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    addPlayer1.doClick();
                    addPlayer2.doClick();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    addPlayer1.doClick();
                    addPlayer2.doClick();
                    addPlayer3.doClick();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    addPlayer1.doClick();
                    addPlayer2.doClick();
                    addPlayer3.doClick();
                    addPlayer4.doClick();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    addPlayer1.doClick();
                    addPlayer2.doClick();
                    addPlayer3.doClick();
                    addPlayer4.doClick();
                    addPlayer5.doClick();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    addPlayer1.doClick();
                    addPlayer2.doClick();
                    addPlayer3.doClick();
                    addPlayer4.doClick();
                    addPlayer5.doClick();
                    addPlayer6.doClick();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    addPlayer1.doClick();
                    addPlayer2.doClick();
                    addPlayer3.doClick();
                    addPlayer4.doClick();
                    addPlayer5.doClick();
                    addPlayer6.doClick();
                    addPlayer7.doClick();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    addPlayer1.doClick();
                    addPlayer2.doClick();
                    addPlayer3.doClick();
                    addPlayer4.doClick();
                    addPlayer5.doClick();
                    addPlayer6.doClick();
                    addPlayer7.doClick();
                    addPlayer8.doClick();

                    break;
                default:
                    return;
        }

        lastNumPlayers = numPlayers;
    } else {        
        //Loop through all players between the last number and the new number
        for(int i = numPlayers + 1; i <= lastNumPlayers; i++) {
            switch(i) {
                //Lowest number of players is 1, so lowest check is at 2 (1+1 = 2)
                case 2:
                    player2.removeAll();
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    player3.removeAll();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    player4.removeAll();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    player5.removeAll();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    player6.removeAll();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    player7.removeAll();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    player8.removeAll();
            }
        }

        //After removing unused players, redraw screen
        repaint();
        lastNumPlayers = numPlayers;
    }

});
```